# How Do I Install an Older Version of GraphicsMagick?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am trying to set up a Ubuntu 16.04LTS machine to host some software that is dependent on `Graphics Magick 1.3.18`.

I've tried to install it by `apt-get install` and also by adding the `ppa:dhor/myway` PPA. Each time I've ended up with `Graphics Magick 1.3.23` which at this point, the software cannot work with. I've also tried to install from source by doing:

```
wget ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/1.3/GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz
tar -xvf GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.gz && cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.18
./configure
make
```

This didn't seem to work properly for me, as I didn't get any output from `gm -version`.

What is the correct way to install the required older version of Graphics Magick?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link: [download GraphicsMagick](http://bbgentoo.ilb.ru/distfiles/)
where you can find GraphicsMagick-1.3.18.tar.xz
After downloading go to download directory and decompress:

```
tar xf [filename]
```

This will expand the contents of the file to a folder. Then the commands are, from the folder:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```